# How to aggregate many marshalled (json) objects to one file

Tags: apache-camel, aggregate

I created a route to buffer/store marshaled objects (json) into files. This route (and the other route to read the buffer) work fine. 
storing in buffer:

```
from(DIRECT_IN).marshal().json().marshal().gzip().to(fileTarget());
```

reading from buffer:

```
from(fileTarget()).unmarshal().gzip().unmarshal().json().to("mock:a")
```

To reduce i/o i want to aggregate many exchanges in one file. I tried to just aggregate after json and before it so i added this after json() or from(...):

```
.aggregate(constant(true)).completionSize(20).completionTimeout(1000).groupExchanges()
```

In both cases i get conversion exceptions. How to do it correctly? I would prefer a way without custom aggregator. And it would be nice if just many exchanges/object are aggregated in one json (as list of objects) or in one text file - one json object per line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using a splitter when reading from the buffer

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile i added a simple aggreagtor:

```
public class LineAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

@Override
public final Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, final Exchange newExchange) {
    //if first message of aggregation
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }
    //else aggregate
    String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String aggregate = oldBody + System.lineSeparator() + newBody;
    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(aggregate);
    return oldExchange;
}
```

}

The routes look like that, to buffer:

```
from(...)// marshal objects to json
                   .marshal()
                   .json()
                   .aggregate(constant(true), lineAggregator)
                   .completionSize(BUFFER_PACK_SIZE)
                   .completionTimeout(BUFFER_PACK_TIMEOUT)
                   .marshal()
                   .gzip()
                   .to(...)
```

from buffer:

```
from(...).unmarshal()
                    .gzip()
                    .split()
                    .tokenize("\r\n|\n|\r")
                    .unmarshal()
                    .json()
                    .to(....)
```

But the question remains, is the aggregator necessary?